# SnackBar at effect spec file

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to test my effect spec file. I'm using matSnackBar in the effect file.
when I run it, the _snackbar is declared as undefined and then the tests field.
this is what i tried to do :

```
describe('InquiryWizardEffects', () => {
let actions: Observable<any>;
let effects: InquiryWizardEffects;
let inquiryService: MockInquiryService;
let _snackBar: MatSnackBar;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            NxModule.forRoot(),
            StoreModule.forRoot({}),
            EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
            MatSnackBarModule,
        ],
        providers: [
            InquiryWizardEffects,
            DataPersistence,
            provideMockActions(() => actions),
            { provide: InquiriesService, useClass: MockInquiryService },
            { provide: MatSnackBar}
        ]
    });
    _snackBar= TestBed.get(MatSnackBar);
    effects = TestBed.get(InquiryWizardEffects);
    inquiryService = TestBed.get(InquiriesService);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Edit

this is the error that i got :

> 'Cannot read property 'openFromComponent' of undefined '

it comes when i am doing :

```
this._snackBar.openFromComponent(CreatedEntitySnackBarComponent, {
            duration:  environment.longDurationSnackBar,
            panelClass: [style],
            horizontalPosition: 'right',
            data: {
                title: title,
                entityId: entityId
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you please present us with the full error?

Comment: Can you try replace`{ provide: MatSnackBar}` with `MatSnackBar` only. Also, remove `_snackBar= TestBed.get(MatSnackBar);` because you are already providing the service and it'll be assigned in `constructor` of the `component`. Let me know if you get any more erros, Also provide `component` code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "useValue" to provide the SnackBar and fake it.

```
describe('InquiryWizardEffects', () => {
let actions: Observable<any>;
let effects: InquiryWizardEffects;
let inquiryService: MockInquiryService;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            NxModule.forRoot(),
            StoreModule.forRoot({}),
            EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
            MatSnackBarModule,
        ],
        providers: [
            InquiryWizardEffects,
            DataPersistence,
            provideMockActions(() => actions),
            { provide: InquiriesService, useClass: MockInquiryService },
            { provide: MatSnackBar, useVale: {openFromComponent: (param1, param2) => { return; }}},
        ]
    });
    effects = TestBed.get(InquiryWizardEffects);
    inquiryService = TestBed.get(InquiriesService);
});
```

Try if this works.